# How solve cannot move directory for WebStorm on WSL?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I work with the Angular project on Windows 10 under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu 18.04). All work's like a charm, but I can't delete or refactor (move) any directory. With files this works fine, but not for directories.

I think problems with permissions for my filesystem, but can't understand how I can fix it. Any know how I can solve it? Refactoring so needed future :)

update: After start command in Linux console, like `ng serve` - refactoring has broken. After restart OS - all work's fine.

update: Issue in WebStorm tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34797

Comment: What is the permission of that folder in `stat` command?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx). Today I can use refactoring, before I use any Linux command. I have run `ng serve` and after it, I can't do refactoring anymore before I restart my OS.

Comment: 4 years after, still not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like WSL blocking problem, not a Webstorm bug.

For detail, you can read JetBrains answer https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34797

Comment: For a quick solution try closing ng serve, then try to move the folders. what I did: closed ng serve, restarted Webstorm (might not be required), and then before running ng serve again, moving the folders worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to **close WebStorm** and move the directory from the **native window** (on Windows or Linux).

Comment: Yeah, but we want to take advantage of the "refactoring" functionality of WS and not replacing all urls manually

Answer (score 0):

For me it happens when I'm trying to copy an exists module to other new generated module.

But after checking I suspect that it was opened in the terminal on this folder, so it wasn't able to make there actions.

It's worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with WebStorm on Windows 10, unable to refactor a folder (moving it, for instance). The file lock was from a Node.js process, but killing the Node.js process was not sufficient because WebStorm restarted the process immediately. I did not identify which process was reopened, but I suspect it was either the TypeScript compiler (tsc) or a JavaScript-based linter. To prevent the process from restarting, I had to CLOSE ALL THE OPENED TABS in WebStorm. Then I identified the Node.js process and killed it using the method described on [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows). (Perhaps using the process manager would be enough to get the running Node.js sub-processes.)

Then only, I have been able to refactor my code as expected